# Using GNU sed, is there a way to put the filename in the pattern space?

Tags: sed

I can print the current filename with GNU sed using "F". I can make changes to the pattern space with "s" (and other commands). Is there any way to put the filename into the pattern space so I can manipulate this as well.

For example:

```
09:24:25:~  $ sed -n 'F ; s/hello/goodbye/ig ; p' hello.txt 
hello.txt
goodbye world
09:24:42:~  $
```

Is there a thing I could put instead of "F" which would get this to result in:

```
goodbye.txt
goodbye world
```

Answer (score 2):

Piping back to `sed` should work

```
$ sed 'F' hello.txt | sed -n 's/hello/goodbye/p'
goodbye.txt
goodbye world
```

Comment: Thanks. That's the conclusion I was coming to but I'd still prefer an option in a single script / process if possible.

Comment: @RichardWheeldon Unfortunately, I do not think it will be possible in a single call. If you do not want to pipe, how about `sed -n 's/hello/goodbye/p' <(sed 'F' hello.txt)`?

Answer (score 2):

This can be done in a single `gnu awk` like this:

```bash
awk -v IGNORECASE=1 '
NR==1{$0 = FILENAME "\n" $0} {gsub(/hello/, "goodbye")} 1' hello.txt

goodbye.txt
goodbye world
```

Comment: Awesome solution in a single call! Nice!!!

Comment: Nice that it's a single script. Not perfectly answering the question in that it's awk not sed.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '1{h;s/.*/sed -n 1F file/e;x};G' file
```

This appends the file name to each line i.e. the file name is held in the  hold space.

For line one only, copy current pattern space to the hold space. Replace the line by another sed scripts output which evaluates to the current file name. Swap the hold space for the pattern space.

For each line append the hold space.

Comment: Not entirely sure I follow this one. Seems to work only if the filename is also in the script itself - at which point the call seems a bit redundant.